# How can I filter child categories of "uncategorized" out of the loop?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have some utility categories that are only used by my theme. How can I make sure that any call to categories excludes the child categories under "uncategorized"?

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of:

```
wp_list_categories(array(
    "exclude" => get_cat_ID("Uncategorized")
));
```

Comment: That doesn't meet the "any calls to wp_list_categories()" requirement.